# QGIS georeferenced layers slightly out

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am georeferencing three different maps that include collected data. I take pictures of the maps in order to georeference them (with as near the same set up for all e.g., tripod distance etc). I save the GCP points for each map and load them each time for the corresponding map. I move the GCP points as needed. I am using a Linear transformation, as I am under the impression that this is appropriate for such an image with the data I have collected.

I have blank versions of these maps already georeferenced in QGIS (didn't save their GCP points back then!), and I can see these align nicely with web map layers e.g., Google Satellite and ESRI Ocean.

However, for a few of the data maps I am georeferencing, they are just slightly off, regardless if I add more GCP points or try other transformations other than Linear (which I have been using and its been fine!).

I assume it is the angle of the image but what am I missing?

Comment: Some screenshots would add a lot of value to your question.

Comment: Helmert & Nearest Neighbour might provide better results.

Comment: Thanks both. I have tried this transformation and resampling method and still I encounter the same problem. In terms of screenshot, due to confidentiality I can't post screenshots sorry.

Comment: Do you have any way to scan the maps instead of taking pictures? Lens deformation might cause some issues

Comment: That's a really interesting point thank you Kasper. The maps are quite large and drawn on in the field, so scanning them would be difficult to do when needed! Do you think the perspective distortion of the image is an issue? e.g., how I take the photos of the maps?